# Converting web.config Url rewrite to .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, iis, web-config, apache2

I have switched from a Windows Server 2008 R2 running IIS7.5 to CentOS server running Apache2, as I had performance problems with PHP.

My main site's Web.config uses url rewrite and needs to be converted. It has been a while since I last used .htaccess files.
My Web.Config rewrite code:

```
  <rule name="IndexRewrite" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url="^([^/]+)/?$" />
        <conditions>
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
        </conditions>
        <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php?p={R:1}" />
    </rule>
```

So what it does is Rewriting the **?p=** That is used by PHP to display the appropriate page.
So, how exactly can this be done? I am not familiar with mod_rewrite in Apache2.

I tried to modify a rewrite rule from another site using SocialEngine, nut no luck.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  Options +FollowSymLinks
  RewriteEngine On

  # Get rid of index.php
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /index\.php
  RewriteRule (.*) index.php?p= [L,QSA]
  # Rewrite all directory-looking urls
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /$
  RewriteRule (.*) index.php?p= [L,QSA]


</IfModule>
```

Example of the link:
http://example.com?p=about
Should be
http://example.com/about

---

That's how it was before when I used IIS7.5 Url rewrite.

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have successfully converted it to a working .htaccess mod_rewrite code.
It seems easier than it is. I had to search deeper in Google and found a working toturial.

Here's the code that I use now.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^([A-z]+)$ /index.php?p=$1
```

So this is solved. ;)